# Why elif statement instead of if statement?

Tags: python

Why should I use an elif instead of using if statements over and over again.
I can't find any documentation on the matter.  Thank you in advance.

Comment: you really only need it if there are >= 3 conditions and one of them is an `else`

Comment: One big reason is that multiple `if` statements are considered independent statements and therefore would each get checked, regardless of if one passes the condition in the chain. In an `if-elif` chain, the condition checking is over if any of the statements pass.

Comment: @PaulH Not necessarily, there are many good reasons to use `if / elif` without an `else`, even for only 2 conditions

Comment: @Yvette It's a dupe of [multiple](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22782785/when-to-use-if-vs-elif-in-python) [questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9271712/difference-between-multiple-ifs-and-elifs-python).

Comment: What I find nowhere in the answers to previous questions is the connection between Pythons use of mandatory indentation and the fact that elif is really needed (as explained in my answer, and as opposed to e.g. in C, C++, Java and JavaScript). This is also why the C/C++ preprocesor needs an #elif but the language itself doesn't have an elif. So perhaps we could consider this question not a complete duplicate having many complete answers.

Comment: Thank you for all of the information.  I know that it was best practices but I couldn't find the reasoning.  Thank you for all the answers.

Answer (score 5):

You use `if`, `elif` and `else` if you want **one and only one** of the cases to execute. In other words, the cases are mutually exclusive.

It also allows for short-circuiting logic. Upon find the first `if` of `elif` that is `True`, you can skip checking the conditions for all following cases. If you simply had a series of `if` statements, you'd have to check all of their conditions no matter what.

Answer (score 4):

Consider the differences, between the first `if`/`elif` group and the second group of `if`s:

```
x = 0

if x == 0:
    print("Zero")
elif x % 2 == 0:
    print("Even")
elif x % 2 == 1:
    print("Odd")

print('---')

if x == 0:
    print("Zero")
if x % 2 == 0:
    print("Even")
if x % 2 == 1:
    print("Odd")
```

In the first, output will only be:

```
Zero
```

In the second, output will be:

```
Zero
Even
```

By using `if`/`elif`, once a condition has been met, the rest of that "ladder" will be skipped.  By using a bunch of individual `if`s, each will be tested, and a single variable can meet multiple conditions (as `x` does here).

There certainly are reasons for each, but it's important to know the differences

Comment: Thank you.  To save my life i couldn't find any reasoning.  I knew it was best practice but I didn't understand why.  Thanks again!!!!

Answer (score 2):

The elif statement is only called it the first if statement is false. Consider the following example:

```
if foo==2:
   print("foo is exactly 2")
elif foo%2 == 0:
   print("foo is not 2 but divisible by 2")
```

If you would use two if statements, in the case of foo==2, both messages would be printed.

Answer (score 1):

The fact that Python has an elif, whereas other languages using {} to delimit blocks don't, is indentation.
Without it you would have to have a very wide screen in some cases...

You'd have to write:

```
if a:
    pass
else:
    if b:
        pass
    else:
        if c:
            pass
        else:
            pass
```

Rather then:

```
if a:
    pass
elif b:
    pass
elif c:
    pass
else:
    pass
```

Languages with that don't use mandatory indentation would allow you to write:

```
if (a) {
    // pass
}
else if (b) {
    // pass
}
else if (c) {
    // pass
}
else {
    // pass
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you write:

```
if a:
    do_something1()
if b:
    do_something2()
```

the two conditions are independent of each other. If both `a` and `b` evaluate to `True`, therefore, both `do_something*` function calls will be made. If instead you write

```
if a:
    do_something1()
elif b:
    do_something2()
```

then if `a` evaluates to `True` then `do_something1` will be callsed, but not `do_something2` - even if `b` is also true. So the `elif` construct allows you to easily specify mutually exclusive conditions.